# Add better javascript support in VS 2010, tips?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio, plugins

I'm writing a lot of javascript code in my visual studio projects. I would like to know if there is any plugins or something similar that could improve this in Visual Studio 2010. And by improving i mean stuff like smarter intellisense, go to definitions etc. Basically the features that you get when writing c# code. Any tips are more than welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) extends JavaScript support significantly. As BNL suggested, Telerik's [Just Code](http://www.telerik.com/products/justcode.aspx) plugin also provides a lot of added functionality.

Comment: Yep, i just tried Resharper 6 and it has some pretty good js support :)

Comment: Resharper is pretty awesome, but it is a gluttonous pig when it comes to resources.

Answer (score 0):

Telerik Just Code does a bunch of cool stuff with js.

http://www.telerik.com/products/justcode.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[JScript Editor Extensions](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/872d27ee-38c7-4a97-98dc-0d8a431cc2ed/) for VS2010 are nice too and worth installing.